# Why is Internet Explorer not returning HTTP 200 with a multipart/form and AJAX post?

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, ajaxform

I am trying to use a multipart/form-data HTML form to do a file upload to a servlet.  I am using jQuery and the ajaxForm plugin. On the response back a check is done to see what the HTTP status code is.  In Chrome and Firefox on success of the servlet the HTTP code is correct with a 200.

In Internet Explorer it appears whenever I have the enctype to be multipart/form-data the HTTP response code is 0 and the readystate is undefined.

See the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var options = { 
        target:        '#status',   
        success:       onSuccess  
    }; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 
function onSuccess(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    alert('HTTP Status: ' + xhr.status + '\r\nReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState); 
} 

})();       
</script>
</head>
<body >
    <div>
        <form id="myForm" action="htmlFormTest.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           Sample Text: <input type="text" name ="sample" id="sample" value="sample" />
            <input type="submit" value="Go!">
        </form>
    </div>

     <div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I have a "normal" form, it works fine...just seems to be with multipart. Also, using Wireshark and HTTPWatch, I can see that the actual HTTP response is a 200 and worked fine. The actual HTTP packets are the same when I compare in Wireshark between IE and Firefox.

Stumped....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and it turned out that the file was on the disk , If the same case is with you then test the page by putting it on a web server.

Reference:
http://www.pearweb.com/javascript/XMLHttpRequest.html

Comment: Thanks for checking on this...My sample I have placed on a server so its not local and the post goes somewhere else. The post dest is the same as the host.  The file upload works fine, but the response is messed up in IE. I can't check the http status code for some reason.

Comment: what is xhr.statusText returning in Firefox ?

Comment: statusText = 'n/a' in IE for me.